# redirect old query URL to new rewritten URL .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've successfully made my urls clean using parameters

from example.com/index.php?gender=m&height=70&weight=150

into example.com/m/70/150/

so if someone types in that clean URL, they'll get the page with the proper parameters.

However, I want to make it so if someone types in the old url, it will 301 redirect to the new clean URL

I've tried this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gender=([a-z]+)&height=([0-9-]+)&weight=([0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

but it is not working, no error, no rewrite.. the URL just looks like the old one still.

Edit:

Current rewrite to make URL's look clean

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^([m]+)en/([0-9-]+)-inches/([0-9-]+)-lbs/?$    index.php?gender=$1&height=$2&weight=$3    [NC,L]
```

Comment: What's your othe rrule look like?

Comment: well it's kinda hacked together..but it's functional (see edit above for clean version)

I have it so  
example.com/index.php?gender=m&height=70&weight=150
will change into   example.com/men/70-inches/150-lbs/


    `RewriteEngine on`

    `RewriteRule    ^([m]+)en/([0-9-]+)-inches/([0-9-]+)-lbs/?$    index.php?gender=$1&height=$2&weight=$3    [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be checking against the actual request as opposed to the URI/query-string because both of those get modified by other rules. There's also something you're missing in the redirect, the `en`, `-inches`, and `-lbs` in part of the cleaner looking URI.

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?gender=([a-z]+)&height=([0-9-]+)&weight=([0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1en/%2-inches/%3-lbs/? [L,R=301]
```